# (h, w) = image.shape[:2] AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, opencv

I have been trying to implement OpenCv CSRT algorithm for object tracking. Below is the code.

```
from imutils.video import VideoStream
from imutils.video import FPS
import argparse
import imutils
import time
import cv2
file1 = 'traffic.mp4'

tracker = cv2.TrackerCSRT_create()
initBB = None
vs = cv2.VideoCapture(file1)
fps = None

while True:
    frame = vs.read()
    
    if frame is None:
        break

    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=500)
    (H, W) = frame.shape[:2]

    if initBB is not None:
        (success, box) = tracker.update(frame)
        if success:
            (x, y, w, h) = [int(v) for v in box]
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        
        fps.update()
        fps.stop()
        
        info = [
            ("Tracker", "CSRT"),
            ("Success", "Yes" if success else "No"),
            ("FPS", "{:.2f}".format(fps.fps())),
        ]
    
        for (i, (k, v)) in enumerate(info):
            text = "{}: {}".format(k, v)
            cv2.putText(frame, text, (10, H - ((i * 20) + 20)),
                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.6, (0, 0, 255), 2)

    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    
    if key == ord("s"):
        initBB = cv2.selectROI("Frame", frame, fromCenter=False, showCrosshair=True)
        tracker.init(frame, initBB)
        fps = FPS().start()

    
    elif key == ord("q"):
        break
        
vs.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I got the code from https://www.pyimagesearch.com/. But they have implemented the code for both webcam and videocapture option in addition to running it from the command line. But I just wanted to run in my IDLE for the videocapture option. So I have modified a bit to run in IDLE. But when I run it, I am getting the following error

```
line 20, in <module> frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=500)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\imutils\convenience.py", line 69, in resize
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Could you please point me towards the right direction.

Comment: Is file1 in your current working directory where your script resides. If not, provide the full path to it.

Comment: Please make sure that you show an error message and code example that actually corrspond to each other. Also, please try to do at least a little bit of your own debugging first. For example, did you try checking what the *type* for `frame` is before the call? Did you try checking the documentation to see what it expects?

Comment: `vs.read()` returns a tuple; it does not return the image directly.

Comment: @fmw42 yeah it's in my current directory. So didn't include the full path.

Answer (score 2):

The function `.read()` returns a bool (`True/False`) and a frame (an **array**). If the frame is read correctly, it will be `True`. So you should change the `frame = vs.read()` to `_, frame = vs.read()` as following (I hope it should work if there is no other errors):

```
...

while True:
    _, frame = vs.read()
      
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=500)
    (H, W) = frame.shape[:2]
    ...
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, it works. Sorry I couldn't upvote as this is my first question in stackoverflow and I need 15 reputation to upvote something. I am new to opencv (just started day before yesterday) but have used python for past 2 years and have never come across this syntax, "_, variable_name". Could you please explain what it does in general or provide me with a link on where I can learn about that as I cannot land a good google search about that.

Comment: @GautamBaskaran, here it has no any specific reason. It's just a variable here or you may write `a, frame = vs.read()`.